# MySQL about constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

Good afternoon,

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code on PHP MY ADMIN, I'm trying to write a CONSTRAINT and create values for the car color in the beginning ( with table creation)

```
CREATE TABLE T_CAR
(CAR_ID                INTEGER       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 CAR_MARK            CHAR(32)      NOT NULL,
 CAR_MODEL            VARCHAR(16),
 CAR_NUMBER   CHAR(10)      NOT NULL,
 CAR_COLOR           CHAR(16)      CHECK (VALUE IN ('white', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'blue')))
```

The problem is with the last line (error message syntax not known).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you should use the enum type instead of a check constraint? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: I've juste tried it, I have the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL ignores `check` expression.

Manual: [Create Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Try Enum:

```
CREATE TABLE T_CAR (
    CAR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CAR_MARK CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CAR_MODEL VARCHAR(16),
    CAR_NUMBER CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CAR_COLOR ENUM('white', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'blue') NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Sorry, now I have this message
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ('white', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'blue') NOT NULL)

Comment: @J.Doe, How did it work before and how not now? What has changed? Would be helpful if you could put some details.